# What is the relationship between Linear Combination and Linear System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

My guess is that it has either to do with finding the solution to a system of linear equations. Honestly this question is so broad i'm confused, that's why i'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $b$ is an $n\times 1$ column-vector, then solving the system $$Ax=b$$ is equivalent to expressing $b$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  For example, if $n=3$ and then solving the system  $$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}\end{bmatrix}$$ is equivalent to finding $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $$x_1\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\{a_31}\end{bmatrix}
+x_2\begin{bmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\\{a_32}\end{bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}a_{13}\\a_{23}\\{a_33}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$
as you can easily verify.